# Blender GUI error after install

Tags: color, error, installation

I have a strange start screen of Blender 2.8 on a MacOS 10.11.6 as you can see below....
I am not quite sure what is going on. 
It is a clean install after a MacOS reinstall. I had an older version of blender that worked fine.

Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Blender 2.80 requires macOS 10.12 or later](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/), your operating system is not supported. You can still use Blender 2.79 and earlier versions, all new versions will require an operating system upgrade.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed I installed 2.79 and the issue is gone.